# SQLite insert select result multiple times

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with three tables 'contacts', 'names', and 'contact_names'.

```
create table contacts(id integer, gid integer, sid integer);
create table names(id integer primary key, name text);
create table contact_names(fullname text);

insert into names(name) values ('Eberhard');
insert into names(name) values ('Esche');

insert into contacts values(1, (select id from names where name='Eberhard'), (select id from names where name='Esche'));
```

Now I want to insert the pair 'given name+surname' twice, once as 'given name+surname' and once as 'surname+given name'. What I currently have is a statment like this to generate these names:

```
SELECT gTable.name || ' ' || sTable.name AS name1, sTable.name || ' ' || gTable.name AS name2 FROM
(
  SELECT name FROM names WHERE id=2
) AS gTable,
(
  SELECT name FROM names WHERE id=1
) AS sTable;
```

What I am not able to perform is to insert these names now to table 'contact_names' using something like this:

```
INSERT INTO contact_names VALUES (name1), (name2) WITH
SELECT gTable.name || ' ' || sTable.name AS name1, sTable.name || ' ' || gTable.name AS name2 FROM
(
  SELECT name FROM names WHERE id=2
) AS gTable,
(
  SELECT name FROM names WHERE id=1
) AS sTable;
```

As result table 'contact_names' shall contain the two entries (rows) "Esche Eberhard" and "Eberhard Esche". Does anyone have a clue how to achieve this? Of course I could do the select statement twice, but I would prefer to do this with one select.

BR, Udo

PS: Maybe it is useful to explain why I want to do that. The INSERT statement for 'contact_names' shall be performed by a trigger that is called on removal of entries from 'contacts'. If I remove a row for instance with

```
DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id=1;
```

then the two name combination of that contact shall be inserted into 'contact_names' (for further handling of these names). The table will be cleared regularily after handling the removed names.

Comment: This seems like a very strange requirement.  It appears that first and last names are being stored in different _records_ in the `names` table, yet you want to pivot that, and also duplicate a first/last combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one row with two columns, but you want two rows with one column.

In the general case, this can be done with a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) and a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
WITH TwoColumns(a, b) AS (
  SELECT a, b FROM ...       -- the original two-column query
)
INSERT INTO ...(x)
SELECT a FROM TwoColumns
UNION ALL
SELECT b FROM TwoColumns;
```

In this case, we don't need so many subqueries and can simplify a little:

```
WITH gs(gName, sName) AS (
    SELECT g.name,
           s.name
    FROM names AS g,
         names AS s
    WHERE g.id = 2
      AND s.id = 1
)
INSERT INTO contact_names(fullname)
SELECT gName || ' ' || sName FROM gs
UNION ALL
SELECT sName || ' ' || gName FROM gs;
```

Comment: Thank you for that solution, it solved the problem. I just want to mention that sqlite3 version 3.8.2 does not understand this syntax, I always get an error message that there is a problem in the WITH statement. Using sqlite3 version 3.11.0 on another machine, the statement works, so obviously the old version does not support this kind of WITH.